# How can I return the matched value from env::var?

Tags: rust, match

If the environment variable `SOMEVALUE` is found, it should be bound to `k`:

```
let k = match env::var(SOMEVALUE) {
    Ok(val) => {return val},
    Err(e) => println!("could not find {}: {}", SOMEVALUE, e),
};
```

Compiling this code gives the following error

```
   |
11 |         Ok(val) => {return val},
   |                            ^^^ expected (), found struct `std::string::String`
   |
   = note: expected type `()`
              found type `std::string::String`
```

Comment: You should read the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/)

Comment: @Stargateur I have actually read the book and particularly the page about `match`. This page however, does not describe how to extract the value from `Ok` which is part of the `Result` struct.

Comment: @duck you can always consult the Rust std docs to find details applicable to specific cases (in this case [Result docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What Victor wrote is correct, but you probably want to actually bind a value to `k`; in that case you should change your code to:

```
let k = match env::var(SOMEVALUE) {
    Ok(val) => val,
    Err(e) => panic!("could not find {}: {}", SOMEVALUE, e),
};
```

Equivalently, you can use [`Result::unwrap_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or_else):

```
let k = env::var(SOMEVALUE).unwrap_or_else(|e| {
    panic!("could not find {}: {}", SOMEVALUE, e)
});
```

Comment: Once you mentioned the `unwrap_or_else` I remembered that there was also a `unwrap` without the error handling.  So I went with the `unwrap`.

Answer (score 4):

In Rust, everything is an expression, there are only a few statements. Each expression returns a value and if the expression does not return anything explicitly, it returns a `()` (unit) value implicitly.

Your `match` expression returns different types from 2 branches - a `std::String` from `Ok` branch and `()` from `Err` branch.

To fix this, you must return something from the second branch too:

```
let k = match env::var(SOMEVALUE) {
    Ok(val) => {return val},
    Err(e) => {
        println!("could not find {}: {}", SOMEVALUE, e);

        String::default()
    },
};
```

This returns a value of the same type - `std::String`.

Comment: I don't think that the OP want this behavior: "What i am trying to achieve with this piece of code is that if the environment variable SOMEVALUE is found, it is bound to k."

Comment: Would it then not be better to move away from the match statement as a whole here to prevent having to do a string comparison to check if there was an error  ?

Answer (score 0):

Another option you can do is following (This just shows how we can use `env::var_os` to achieve same purpose)

```
let spdk_dir = match env::var_os("SPDK_DIR") {
    Some(val) => val.into_string().unwrap(),
    None => panic!("SPDK_DIR is not defined in the environment")
};
```

Here, we try to read the environment variable `SPDK_DIR` and if it is not defined, we exit the program.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for the comment. Adapted.

Comment: I apologize that I wasn't clear. The top-voted answer already uses a `match` and a `panic`. I was trying to ask what the difference is between this answer and that one.

Comment: @Shepmaster different flavor I assume. Instead of `env::var`, I use `env::var_os`

Comment: Perhaps you can [edit] your answer to explain to future visitors *why* they should favor this answer as opposed to one of the others? What tradeoffs are different with this answer? While you use `var_os`, you convert it to a `String` and then panic if that fails (via `unwrap`), so I'm not yet clear on the benefit.